# Plotting a bar chart in R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, bar-chart, mutate

```
# A tibble: 6 × 7
  No    Region     District `Name of School`  Male Female Total
  <chr> <fct>      <fct>    <chr>            <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 1     South East Gaborone Bokamoso CJSS      545    516  1061
2 2     South East Gaborone Marang CJSS        550    567  1117
3 3     South East Gaborone Nanogang CJSS      493    558  1051
4 4     South East Gaborone Maikano CJSS       440    388   828
5 5     South East Gaborone Motswedi CJSS      443    475   918
6 6     South East Gaborone Gaborone West      415    401   816
```

i want to declare and add a new categorical variable Gender to my data. the gender variable should depend on the values of males and females already provided in the dataset. The point is to plot a grouped bar chart where Region is divided into gender categories in the x axis

```
# A tibble: 6 × 7
  No    Region     District `Name of School`  Male Female Total
  <chr> <fct>      <fct>    <chr>            <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 1     South East Gaborone Bokamoso CJSS      545    516  1061
2 2     South East Gaborone Marang CJSS        550    567  1117
3 3     South East Gaborone Nanogang CJSS      493    558  1051
4 4     South East Gaborone Maikano CJSS       440    388   828
5 5     South East Gaborone Motswedi CJSS      443    475   918
6 6     South East Gaborone Gaborone West      415    401   816
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Adding a basic approach in base R:

```r
X = df[, c("Name.of.School", "Male", "Female")] 
X[-1] |>
  t() |> 
  `colnames<-`(X$Name.of.School) |>
  barplot(beside = TRUE, col = c("lightblue", "red2"), legend = c("M", "F"))
```

[image]

Data

```r
df = data.frame(
  No = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"),
  Region = factor(rep("South East", 6)), District = factor(rep("Gaborone", 6)),
  `Name of School` = c("Bokamoso CJSS", "Marang CJSS", "Nanogang CJSS", 
                       "Maikano CJSS", "Motswedi CJSS", "Gaborone West"),
  Male = c(545, 550, 493, 440, 443, 415), Female = c(516, 567, 558, 388, 475, 401),
  Total = c(1061, 1117, 1051, 828, 918, 816))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn [`tidy` data principles](https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf) first

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Create the dataframe df
df <- tibble(
  No = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"),
  Region = factor(rep("South East", 6)),
  District = factor(rep("Gaborone", 6)),
  `Name of School` = c("Bokamoso CJSS", "Marang CJSS", "Nanogang CJSS", "Maikano CJSS", "Motswedi CJSS", "Gaborone West"),
  Male = c(545, 550, 493, 440, 443, 415),
  Female = c(516, 567, 558, 388, 475, 401),
  Total = c(1061, 1117, 1051, 828, 918, 816)
)

df %>% 
  select(-Total) %>% 
  pivot_longer(c(Male, Female), names_to = "gender", values_to = "schools") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(`Name of School`, y = schools, fill = gender)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>